# How do I load an existing public and private key pair into SSH?

Tags: ssh, permissions

I have a SSH public and private key pair (files) from a previous Linux installation along with the corresponding pass phrase:

```
~/id_rsa.pub
~/id_rsa.ppk
```

When I try to add the private key I get a warning message:

```
$ ssh-add id_rsa.ppk
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0444 for 'id_rsa.ppk' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
```

What is the correct way to do this?  I am using Linux Mint 18.1.

**Update** I found a solution on this page: https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux

Comment: A `.ppk` file is probably a PuTTY private key file - the format is different from that used by OpenSSH. You can use PuTTY's `puttygen` to convert to an OpenSSH compatible format.

Comment: I found a solution on this page: https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux

Comment: Also related: [What permissions should each file under ```.ssh``` have?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/163194/80216) and [Error: permission denied through ssh](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/312608/80216).

Answer (score 5):

Fix the permissions (by removing group and world permissions altogether):

```
chmod go= ~/id_rsa.ppk
```

then add it:

```
ssh-add ~/id_rsa.ppk
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard permissions for SSH files in your `~/.ssh` directory are:

~/.ssh: `700`

id_rsa : `600`

id_rsa.pub: `644`

authorized_keys: `644`